# Is there something like npmjs for Scala / Java

Tags: java, scala, maven, dependencies, sbt

Is there a repository search for Scala similar to [npmjs](http://npmjs.com) for Node? I found [Maven](http://search.maven.org) which has a lot of results. But there is no description nor usage information which is easily accessible.

I'm using SBT. As build and dependency tool.

Other languages have them, is Scala lacking in this?

For example:

[Objective C / Swift](http://cocoapods.org)
[PHP](https://packagist.org)

Answer (score 2):

In Java world maven repositories are the default. They don't contain any user-friendly data, just artifacts easy for download(binaries, source code, docs). For high level description of libraries you need to google them.